# Strange Behavior in Building a Project Using a .lib File

Tags: visual-studio-2008, lnk2001

I am using visual studio 2008. I am trying to use a C++ library in my source code. After installing the library on my computer, I have some include files as well as some library files. In addition, in the bin folder there are msvcm80.dll, msvcp80.dll, and msvcr80.dll.

I have a problem in linking the project which I have explained below. I searched online but I didn't find a relative answer to my question.

I did the following procedures:

1. I used Explorer Lib software and found out that the .lib files are built in release configuration.
2. I set the visual studio solution to be built in release mode for 32 bit. I was not sure whether I should use 32 or 64. (Below I explained what happens when I change this to x64 platform).
3. I added the library files to the linker dependencies and their path in the additional library directories.
4. I included the header file in the source code.
5. When I try to build the solution, I get the error "LNK2001: unresolved external symbol" on the function that I called in my source code. I get the same error even if I remove the library dependency and delete their path in the linker configuration.

My question is that why the linker does not locate the called functions in my source code in the library files?

When I change the platform from Win32 to x64, I get the error LNK 2001 but on another function. The difference is that the linker is complaining about a function which I have not called directly in my source code.

Could someone kindly help me identify the cause of this error? Please let me know if I did not explain my problem clearly.

Thanks,

Ahmad

Comment: Maybe it is a C library so you have to write the #include in extern "C" {}  This is just guessing, contact the library owner for support.

Comment: It is a c++ library. I would be grateful to have your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

You must give more details, maybe some (of the first) error messages.

Getting the linker settings right in VS has never been an easy task. Some points you can check:

- if using winsock libraries, check which is included first, etc. (the famous winsock.h vs winsock2.h)
- Check the Platform Toolset (in your case it should probably be v80)
- Last and not least, if the missing externals are Windows APIs maybe you need to specify in the Linker\Additional Dependencies things like: User32.lib, Shell32.lib,Oleaut32.lib,Advapi32.lib depending on the APIs used.